# Why are Airflow/Composer Macros are not interpolated/Interpreted?

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am not sure if this is normal behavior, but I try to run a command using `gsutil` within a `python_callable` in a `BranhPythonOperator`... This command works well when I use it explicitly on my terminal with the hardcoded paths within `GCS`, but once I try to run it within my DAG using `{{ds_nodash}}` and `{{run_id}}` (Airflow Macros). Airflow does not interpret them, as you can see in the logs below.

[image: Composer Logs]

Here is the code within my DAG definition

```
with DAG("DAG_NAME", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="@hourly", catchup=False) as dag:
    # Buckets
    airflow_bucket = "XXXXX"  # Hidden on purpose
    archive_bucket = "YYYYY"  # Hidden on purpose

    # Paths
    raw_data_path = "raw_data/tc_export/raw/{{ds_nodash}}/{{run_id}}/*"
    airflow_local_dir = "/home/airflow/gcs/data/tc_data/"

    # SFTP & dirs
    sftp_key = "KEY"  # Hidden on purpose
    sftp_remote_directory_root = '/data/from_tc/'

    op_check_if_files_in_sftp = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='check_if_files_in_sftp',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=check_if_files_in_sftp,
        op_kwargs={'remote_directory_root': sftp_remote_directory_root},
        templates_dict={"sftp_key": sftp_key})
    op_check_if_files_in_bucket = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='check_if_files_in_bucket',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=check_if_files_in_bucket,
        op_kwargs={'bucket': archive_bucket, 'subdir': raw_data_path})
```

And here is the function that executes the `gsutil`

```
def check_if_files_in_bucket(bucket: str, subdir: str, **kwargs) -> str:
    """
    Check if files already exist in the archives' bucket.

    :param bucket: bucket in which to search
    :param subdir: directory within the bucket
    :param kwargs: additional context parameters.
    :return: id of the next DAG operator
    """
    try:
        logging.info(f"Executing command : gsutil -q  stat gs://{bucket}/{subdir}")
        command = subprocess.run(["gsutil", "-q", "stat", f"gs://{bucket}/{subdir}"])
        if command.returncode:
            logging.info(f"Command return code : {command.returncode}. Ending process.")
            return "end_process"
        logging.info(f"There are files within the {bucket}/{subdir}. Proceeding with the next step.")
        return "transfer_to_other_bucket"
    except OSError as os_err:
        logging.exception(os_err)
        exit(1)
    except ValueError as val_err:
        logging.exception(val_err)
        exit(1)
```

So my questions are :

1. When does Airflow interpret the Macros?
2. How do I fix this?

Comment: Templates and Macros are a way to pass dynamic data to your DAG at runtime. They are considered place holders and not variables. Can you try to pass these macros to a variable and then use the variables in the paths? Such as : ex_date = '{{ ds_nodash }}' and run_id = '{{ run_id }}' then use the variables in the path.

Comment: I have found the reason it doesn't work. It is due to not using `tempate_dict` to pass the `raw_data_path `. I used `op_kwargs`, which doesn't interpret the templates apparently. I will formulate the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is related to not using the argument `templates_dict` within the `BranchPythonOperator`. Here is the corrected code :

```
op_check_if_files_in_bucket = BranchPythonOperator(task_id='check_if_files_in_bucket',
                                             provide_context=True,
                                             python_callable=check_if_files_in_bucket,
                                             op_kwargs={'bucket': archive_bucket},
                                             templates_dict={'subdir': raw_data_path})
```

And the `python_callable` function :

```
def check_if_files_in_bucket(bucket: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    """
    Check if files already exist in the archives' bucket.

    :param bucket: bucket in which to search
    :param kwargs: additional context parameters, and subdirectory in bucket.
    :return: None
    """
    try:
        subdir = kwargs["templates_dict"]["subdir"]
        cmd_check_files = ["gsutil", "-q", "stat", f"gs://{bucket}/{subdir}"]

        logging.info(f"Executing command : {' '.join(cmd_check_files)}")
        command = subprocess.run(cmd_check_files)
        if command.returncode:
            logging.info(f"Command return code : {command.returncode}. Ending process.")
            return "end_process"
        logging.info(f"There are files within the {bucket}/{subdir}. Proceeding with the next step.")
        return "transfer_to_other_bucket"
    except OSError as os_err:
        logging.exception(os_err)
        exit(1)
    except ValueError as val_err:
        logging.exception(val_err)
        exit(1)
```

N.B : Since `BranchPythonOperator` extends `PythonOperator`, the same rule applies.